# iPad always starts in landscape

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to force my app to start in portrait and be stuck in portrait for the first few views. This works on iPhone and in simulator fine but not when uploaded to iPad. The problem is that no matter what I try it always starts in landscape.

I have the following in the first few views:

```
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
           return false
    }
```

I also tried setting my device orientation to only portrait and set Requires Fullscreen to on, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

In your project target, go to General, then in the Development Info section follow the attached images:

1. Make sure that your app is set to Universal for the supported
   devices
2. Chose iPhone and check Portrait.
3. Chose iPad and check Portrait.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `.plist`. check `Supported interface orientations (iPad)`. Set it only to portrait

[image]